# how to update a record in the table using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table it contains the record .The below is the sample.

```
 $40608$<12988>
```

What we need ?

I need to update the record where it presents in the table using the value "12988"
and again update the value("12988") to 12989.

I have tried to search the record in postgresql using the `LIKE '%<12988>%'`
i need to update the value ($40608$<12988>)

Comment: `$40608$<12988>` I don't want to see benchmarks for more complex queries with this kind of structure... Anyway, what `UPDATE` statement did you use?

Answer (score 3):

testbed:

```
create table t(val text);
insert into t(val) values ('$40608$<12988>');

select * from t;
      val
----------------
 $40608$<12988>
(1 row)
```

update:

```
update t 
set val=replace(val, '<12988>', '<12989>')
where val like '%<12988>';
```

result:

```
select * from t;
      val
----------------
 $40608$<12989>
(1 row)
```